# PHP - create standard zip file with zlib

Tags: php, zip, zlib

I have just now discovered that my hosting server does not support the ZIP class for PHP.

However, it has the Zlib installed and supported .

Is there any library / function / hack / class / that will let me handle ZIP files on such a server ?

Basically I want to create zip files. I am afraid my users will be scared of the GZ extension  and i would like to serve them ZIP extension (that they will open normally on win systems) ?

(please do not tell me to change hosting - I already know I have to , but it will take time and the thing is quite urgent..)

**UPDATE I** . thanks to @Mark Baker - i was able to extract a file with the pclzip class and this simple code

```
<?php

 include('pclzip.lib.php');
  $archive = new PclZip('wp.zip');
  $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  if ($archive->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $location ,
                        PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_PATH, 'install/release') == 0) {
    die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
  }
?>
```

(I just wanted to post the code here , it was too lng for comment ,  and I did not wanted to post another answer  )

Still did not tested the creation, but if it works the same - then I really want to kiss the developers of that class ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zlib doesn't help you create zip files.

As an alternative to your missing ZipArchive, you might take a look at the [PCLZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) library. This is pure PHP, so no need for additional extensions, and allows you to create zip files without ZipArchive.

Comment: Yes, zlib certainly _can_ help you create zip files, since it provides the core compression and crc32 routines required, which are the hard parts.  All you need to do is wrap the compressed data with zip headers and trailers.  PCLZip uses zlib to do just that.

Comment: @Mark Baker - DUDE ! :-) genius . exactly what I wanted . I did not yet tested creation, but already successfully extracted zip file . Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ Mark Adler - ok , interesting . so can you give an example on HOW to do so ? and will it support folders and nesting files (as I understood, zlib does not support that ..)

Comment: I stand corrected about zlib, but still stand by recommending PCLZip as a class that does a lot of useful work when ZipARchive isn't available

Comment: @Mark Baker Thanks again for the effort - and I am not completely sure you are wrong when considering the approach. also @ will has had a similar idea. maybe it can really work . need to test (not sure about CREATION because of nesting and inner folders , but a simple file with the right header might just work .)

Comment: If PCLZip does what you need, then you're set.  If not, you can roll your own using the documentation of the zip format, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format), and ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/doc/appnote-iz-latest.zip .  All a zip file is is a series of file entries followed by a directory of the contents.  Each entry is a header, the compressed data from zlib, and an optional trailer.  The crc32 is in the header or the trailer.  Each entry has the path name of the file, which can contain any depth of directories.  That's all there is to the nesting.

Comment: @MarkAdler thanks again - I´ll check it out. it is interesting. but If there is something already made and tested - I would trust the programming skills of others far more than my own :-)

Comment: FWIW, PCLZip is not pure PHP. It uses gzdeflate() to compress, which may not be available on all builds.

Comment: FWIW, PCLZip is redundant for all supported versions of PHP that come with ZipArchive now

Answer (score 0):

11 years after the latest answer, I came here because of problems in PclZip. It is not really mantained any more.

I have found an excellent alternative, which serves Zip Files whithout the need to save them:

[maennchen/zipstream-php on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/maennchen/zipstream-php)

ZipStream is easy to use and functions out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that on windows the extension only tells it what application to use to open it.

So you could just save it as something winzip will open, and then just rename it...

Comment: do you mean there will be no difference between a GZ file and a ZIP file if I will artificially change the extension on my server and serve it as ZIP ?

Comment: @ninenine no, there is definitely a difference, and it will be misleading for users, but if it is only the windows users you're concerned about. It's really not a good fix though, probably why I got down voted.